# How do I escort a bounty North / South with a gun?

Tags: westerado

I'm trying to escort this bounty back to the sheriff, and I can lead him to the East and West very easily with my gun.

[image: stubborn bounty]

However, he refuses to go to the North and South (top and bottom of screen) in any sort of logical pattern. I assume I'm supposed to follow behind him, nudging him forward, because he wont follow me. But, approaching him directly from the South never makes him move, I always have to be off to one side.

I can approach him, gun out, from the SE direction, and he will sometimes run NW (which makes sense), W (easiest to trigger), and SW (extremely frustrating).

I've seen posts about different tools (e.g. rope) that can lead a bounty around, but can I do it with just a gun? Or is the North/South problem why you need those other tools?